# interface implements an interface

Tags: go

In `../src/io/io.go`, below interface has `Write` method

```
type Writer interface {
    Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

In `../src/net/http/server.go`, below interface `ResponseWriter` implements `Write` method of `Writer` interface

```
type ResponseWriter interface {

    Header() Header

    Write([]byte) (int, error)

    WriteHeader(statusCode int)
}
```

---

From coding style aspect, Is `Writer` interface embed in `ResponseWriter` interface preferred over implementing it?

Comment: It doesn't particularly matter. Preference is just that, preference - a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: @Adrian For a reader who goes through `server.go` first will take time(or may not knew) to understand that `ResponseWriter` is actually implementing `Write` method of `Writer` interface. Embedding type will resolve this problem

Comment: I'm not sure that's relevant. They also don't know if it implements some interface I created that defines `WriteHeader`. It's not up to the implementation to say what interfaces it implements, and it's not up to one interface to say what other interfaces it implements - it can't cover them all because interfaces are duck-typed in Go.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're touching on [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding).

So in your example above, one could rewrite the interface definition like so:

```
type ResponseWriter interface {

    Header() Header

    io.Writer // embedded interface type

    WriteHeader(statusCode int)
}
```

But this is a *pre-arrangement* with the `io` package.

The `http/server.go` interface definition is able to exist without knowledge of the `io` package.

By `http/server.go`'s interface requiring a function `Write` with an identical signature to `io.Writer` allows lots of other benefits without establishing a formal link to the (external) `io` package.

Comment: Advantage of Packaging application? loosely coupled

Comment: @overexchange the tour page expresses it pretty succinctly: https://tour.golang.org/methods/10

Comment: exactly, many packages can (and very much do) rely on io.Reader and io.Writer - without explicitly mention the package `io`. Many packages implement Dial methods to be consistent with other Database connection methods, but don't need to formally agree with a third-party interface definition. But if all databases adhere to the same interface - once can write abstract code and switch from one database to another without changing your client code.

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/go-cloud is a great example of a recent interface by Google to abstract existing cloud services like AWS etc.

Comment: @colminator, I've added this very important observation to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Remember that an interface itself implements nothing at all. It simply says, "if your package implements all these functions with exactly these signatures, then it can be used where an X interface is required".

Think of it as a contractual type: "If I say that a `FooInterface` can be used here, then anything that does all the things I said a `FooInterface` does is acceptable."

A `Writer` by the definition here needs to implement `Write`, somehow. What that particular method *does* is not important from the standpoint of the interface, only that it *exists*, and accepts a `byte` array, returning an `int` and an `error`. What it *does* is up to the implementation of the package.

Maybe it it programs a drone to skywrite the bytes, maybe it hacks the Times Square billboards and prints the message there. All that matters is that, at a minimum, you can call `Write` and get back the expected return values. The side effects are not defined by the interface, but by the implementation in the package.

The fact that a `Write` function exists with the right signature makes the package conform to the `Writer` interface. It could have a dozen other methods; it only matters that `Write` is there to meet the requirement.

`ResponseWriter` and `Writer` are related only in that `ResponseWriter` says "I happen to require that `ResponseWriter`s implement the same interface as a `Writer` - we both implement `Write([]byte) (int, error)`; to be a `ResponseWriter`, it's also necessary to implement `Header` and `WriteHeader`." If the `Skywriting` package also implemented these two functions, then it would be a `ResponseWriter`.

`type ResponseWriter interface` does not define what `Header` and `WriteHeader` do, only that they must *exist* and have the right signature. The relationship to `Writer` is only that we've agreed that *conceptually* a `ResponseWriter` is a specialized `Writer`. It would be perfectly possible to define an `OddResponseWriter` interface that didn't include `Write` (though it would be confusing).

More specialized names *imply* that the interface with the more specialized name is a superset of the one with the simpler name, but there is no enforcement of this by Go itself. We can, as @colminator notes, enforce this by *embedding* the simpler type; this lets the compiler enforce that the specialized interface also meets the less-specialized interface's contract, and ensures that the code will fail to compile if the embedded interface's requirements change but the embedder has not changed to meet it.

This implementation of interfaces gives us a lot of flexibility to substitute one package for another without rewrites. If a function says "please pass me a `Writer` interface so I can write out my results", that code doesn't need to be touched if you swap in a new package with a different name, as long as what you pass in has a `Writer` that matches up.